# Read a file from upstart script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

I need to read a a file from my upstart script in order to determine the environment. The file which store the environment reside in /home/test/env.

This env file content is,

```
export environment=dev
```

How can i read this env file and get the value "dev" to a variable in the upstart script?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to "source" the content?

```
# cat foo
bar=VALUE
# source foo
# echo $bar
VALUE
```

It 'source' the file as a shell script in the current script scope.
You can use "." in place of "source" (. foo)